# $\mathcal{O}_L$ free over $\mathcal{O}_K[G]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be a galois extension of number fields. Suppose $G:=\text{Gal}(L/K)$ is abelian. If $\mathcal{O}_L$ is free as $\mathcal{O}_K[G]$-module, is it true that it has rank 1?

Comment: Do you require that $G$ is abelian? If $\mathcal{O}_L$ is a free $\mathcal{O}_K[G]$ module of rank 1, then it is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_K[G]$ as a ring, which is not commutative if $G$ is nonabelian.

Comment: @oxeimon: yes, thanks!

Comment: @oxeimon, your argument that $G$ has to be abelian is not valid; module structure does not determine the ring structure in general. As an example, if $G$ is any finite group, the commutative ring $R = \bigoplus_{G} \mathbf{C}$ with the obvious $G$-action is certainly a free $\mathbf{C}[G]$-module of rank one (it is the regular representation). OTOH, as noted by the OP, your argument does not make use of the fact that $G$ is abelian anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. Firstly, since $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a Dedekind domain, and $\mathcal{O}_L$ is an integral domain, that means that $\mathcal{O}_L$ is a torsion-free $\mathcal{O}_K$-module, hence flat, hence locally free. Locally free modules over integral domains have a well-defined rank, which is the rank of any localization of the module at a prime. By localizing at $(0)$, we find that $\mathcal{O}_L$ is a locally free $\mathcal{O}_K$ module of rank $[L:K] = |G|$.

On the other hand, $\mathcal{O}_K[G]$ is clearly a free $\mathcal{O}_K$-module of rank $|G|$. If $\mathcal{O}_L$ is a free $\mathcal{O}_K[G]$-module, then it would have to have rank 1 - since $\mathcal{O}_L\ne 0$, it's not rank 0. If it had rank $\ge 2$ over $\mathcal{O}_K[G]$, then since ranks are multiplicative, it would have to have rank $\ge 2|G|$ over $\mathcal{O}_K$, which is not true.

Comment: where do you use that $G$ is abelian?

Comment: @user72870 I don't. $G$ has to be abelian in this case, since the rank considerations above imply that the only way for $\mathcal{O}_L$ to be a free $\mathcal{O}_K[G]$-module is if it is free of rank 1, which would imply that $\mathcal{O}_L\cong\mathcal{O}_K[G]$ as rings, which would imply that $G$ is abelian. If $G$ weren't abelian then $\mathcal{O}_L$ couldn't be a free $\mathcal{O}_K[G]$-module, so there'd be nothing to prove.